# Wordpress query will not allow me to query all my custom posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Basically, I am little unaware of why my WP site can only run a query up to 766 custom post of one type (the actual posts).

I have 26,000 posts that are within one custom post type, but cannot query them all as it only allows me to query the first 766 and then stops on number 767.

EDIT:

From some of the comments I have debugged the website and found no errors to my query problem.I have used define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true); and got no where.

The public URL for you to see can be found here: http://universitycompare.com/test/

As you see here it is only showing 766 custom posts, but when it gets to 767 the query stops and does not work form there on. I need a way to set the Reading settings of 'Blog pages show at most' to unlimited. (or 30k+)

Has anyone faced this problem before? If any idea on how it could be fixed? - I have posted this here as there is no feedback/clues anywhere online but have a feeling it could be a MySQL problem or a Wordpress problem? - I'm just unsure.

Also just FYI, the code i'm using to query can be found here:

```
<?php //wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>

<?php 

// args
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'uc_course',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $object = get_field('university') ?>
        <?php if( $object->post_title == "University of Aberdeen" ) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

Comment: If you bypass the site and query mysql directly how many results do you get?

Comment: I've never actually done that, so if I could see a way too I could do it and get back to you.